# Java - Inheritance and Polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, parent-child

The instructions are these:
Create a Main class which will contain the main method. Implement
the following inside the main method:

– create objects from the regular classes using the overloaded constructors

– test all instance methods (i.e. setters, getters, overloaded, overridden)

– a parent reference assigned to a child object

– a method call which passes a polymorphic object

And I got stuck in my Parent Class which is the Rainforest. What should I do next?

Rainforest Class

```
//INHERITANCE                                                      
  package com.ancient;                                              
  public class Rainforest                                                
  {                                         
  public static void main(String[] args)                                 
  }
```

[Rainforest Class - Inherits Parent and Child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqbSH.png)

Mammal Class (Parent Class)

```
//PARENT CLASS                                                     
  package com.ancient;                                              
  public class Mammal                                                    
  {
//INSTANCE VARIABLES
private String type;
private double speed;

//CONSTRUCTOR
public Mammal(String type, double speed)
{
    this.type = type;
    this.speed = speed;
}

//SETTERS
public void setType(String type) 
{
    this.type = type;
}

public void setSpeed(double speed) 
{
    this.speed = speed;
}

//GETTERS
public String getType() 
{
    return type;
}

public double getSpeed() 
{
    return speed;
}

//OVERRIDDEN
public void hunt(int Food)//int Food is the quantity - how many does the eagle he hunts?
{
    System.out.println("The Bald eagle preys " + Food + "animals within a day to survive.");
}
```

}

[Mammal Class - Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucH0A.png)
[Mammal Class - Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbhdM.png)

Bird (Child Class)

```
package com.ancient;                                                
 public class Bird extends Mammal                                        
 {                                                                  
 public Bird(String type, double speed) 
{
    super(type, speed);
}

//OVERRIDDING
public void hunt(int Food)//int Food is the quantity - how many does the eagle he hunts?
{
    System.out.println("The Bald eagle will prey " + Food + "animals within a day to survive.");                                                  
}                                                                        
}
```

[Bird - Child Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXmPL.png)

My Project content
[Project content > src > package (library) > regular (2) and main classes (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEzQl.png)

Now, the problem here is: my constructor is undefined. Should I make a new package and insert Rainforest class to it? OR there's something wrong with my object in Mammal and Bird Class?

Comment: Don't post pics of your code. Put your code directly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a constructor in your Mammal class that accepts parameters but you are trying to instantiate your objects without passing parameters.

Comment: like this "public Mammal(String type, double speed)"?

Comment: This is how you have defined the constructor in Mammal class. To instantiate a new Mammal object you need to pass parameters to your constructor, e.g. new Mammal("type", 1.0);